# Prompt from read -p not displayed when piping stdout/stderr from script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function designed to capture the output from a command and indent each line:

```
indent_lines () {
  local line
  local indent="        "

  while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
      # remove \r and replace with \r$indent
      echo "$indent $(echo "$line" | sed "s/$(printf '\r')/$(printf '\r')$indent /g")"
  done
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
some command 2>&1 | indent_lines
```

The entire output from `some command 2>&1` is piped into the indent_lines function and each line of output will be indented. This works except in the case where the `read -p` in called from within `some command`, for example:

```
get_name () {
   echo "this is a line of output 1"
   echo "this is a line of output 2"
   echo "this is a line of output 3"
   read -p "enter your name: " user_input
   echo
   echo "$user_input is your name"
}
```

The output is:

```
$ get_name 2>&1 | indent_lines
$        this is a line of output 1
$        this is a line of output 2
$        this is a line of output 3
$
```

The prompt is not displayed and hangs waiting for input.

Is there any way to get the prompt to display before pausing for input?

Comment: I'm confused; you discuss `read -p` but there is no `read -p` in the code except in discussion of a sub-shell, the context of which is not clear either.  Can you please show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Also, `read -p` is primarily Bash, isn't it?  Maybe you should retag with [tag:bash] or add the tag at any rate.

Comment: @Jonathan read -p is invoked in the subshell "$(some command 2>&1 )" and it actually would not matter if it's read -p or just read (i think)

Comment: @ Jonathan I believe the line `The indent_lines function works as intended unless the subshell calls the read command:

read -p "enter something"` does explain it, but i did update with some clarification

Comment: `echo "$(read -p "enter something")"` doesn't make any sense -- you're reading into the REPLY variable, but not *doing* anything with it.

Comment: that said, it **does** write to the screen as-is, no changes needed, unless you're doing something to stderr that you aren't showing in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for having a look. I updated the question to give a precise example.  I hope that helps.  The problem is i do not have access to the get_name() function.  Is there anything i can do to capture it from my end?

Comment: Doesn't help at all. When I run your "precise example", the prompt is correctly printed to the TTY.

Comment: (mind you, as written, it never exits the loop, so we don't get to `"$user_input" is your name`, and thus we never return from the function and get to the `echo` outside).

Comment: Also, why would you run `echo "$(get_name)" | indent_lines` rather than `get_name | indent_lines` (or, to put `get_name` directly in the parent process, `get_name > >(indent_lines)`)? The `echo` and subshell don't do anything useful, and if `get_name` is intended to modify process-local variables, can be actively harmful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are absolutely correct the subshell was totally not necessary and actually was wrong.  I have tested the example just updated and it demonstrates the problem exactly.  Thanks for your patients and help.

Comment: ...yeah, it's the `2>&1` (which I didn't see in earlier revisions) that's breaking the prompt. You're doing that to yourself -- if you don't want to force the prompt to go into your capture, you need to stop using `2>&1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy without `2>&1` the any errors that are output from the command will not be piped into  `indent_lines` and the prompt is not indented.  Perhaps you could modify your answer to obtain the correct output? Keeping in mind i can not modify get_name

Comment: @arctelix, your function is sending both prompts and errors to the same file descriptor. They're thus indistinguishable by nature, unless you do some kind of horrid awful hack like pattern-matching that FD's contents, and I don't support horrid awful hacks (and thus refuse to demonstrate how to commit one).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm sorry, which function indent_lines or get_name.  I don't have access to get_name.  indent_lines is "my function" which i am trying to modify properly output the contents of get_name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112962/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-arctelix).

Comment: BTW, running `sed` once per line of output is *insanely* inefficient. I'd suggest either rewriting your `indent_lines` function so it just calls sed once for the entire stream, or using parameter expansion or other bash-builtin string handling rather than `sed`.

Comment: I will certainly work on that as well

Comment: BashFAQ #100, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100, may be helpful; likewise http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `while read` loop (like many other tools) on the input side is handling a line at a time. Since the prompt isn't printing a newline at the end, it's thus not handled by the loop.

At a high level, you have two options:

- Avoid the pipeline for the prompt
- Add a newline so the content is flushed

Since it's part of the specification that the `get_name` function can't be modified, what we'll end up doing here is modifying the shell environment to alter how `read` works.

---

#### Avoiding the pipeline

`read -p` writes its prompt to stderr.

If you want to redirect the prompt, then redirect FD 2.

If you want to ensure that other redirections (such as a `2>&1`, which would cause the prompt to go to stdout -- which is being captured) don't apply, then direct to the TTY explicitly:

```
read -p "enter something" 2>/dev/tty
```

---

#### Adding a newline

Now, if your goal is to run a shell function -- which you can't modify -- with stderr redirected in general but `read -p` printing prompts directly to the TTY, that *can* be done, with a hack akin to the following:

```
reading_to_tty() {
  read() { builtin read "$@" 2>/dev/tty; }
  "$@"
  unset -f read
}
```

...thus:

```
reading_to_tty get_name 2>&1
```

...will run `get_name`, with `read` commands (and no others) sending stderr content directly to the TTY.

---

Per extended discussion, another approach to ensure that the prompt is flushed to the pipeline formatting it is to append a newline. The below does that, so the existing pipeline through a formatting function can be used:

```
reading_with_prompt_newline() { 
  read() {
    if [[ $1 = -p ]]; then 
      set -- "$1" "$2"$'\n' "${@:3}" 
    fi 
    builtin read "$@" 
  } 
  "$@" 
  unset -f read 
}
```

...used in the same manner as the above:

```
reading_with_prompt_newline get_name
```

Comment: I think your solution is going far away for a shell beginner! ;-) But very interesting solution, at all!